# Angular 2 DatePipe shortTime display is off by 6 hours

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I have a datetime returning as `"2016-12-20T19:00:00"` and am using a the following pipe on it: `{{ dateObj | date:'shortTime' }}` I want/expect that to display as 7:00 PM, but it instead is displaying as 1:00 PM. Is this a bug with Angular, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What timezone are you in? What timezone do you think that time is in?

Comment: You should definitely suspect a timezone issue.  Angular 2 DatePipe spits out localized time.

Comment: The date, apparently, is considered as a UTC date. See http://plnkr.co/edit/SuqPiZKl2P4viJLN7c5i?p=preview. You should specify a timezone offset, and prefer returning UTC dates from your API.

Comment: @JBNizet DatePipe Timezone offsets don't seem to work, even the verbatim examples from the DatePipe documentation don't change the displayed time....